# How to adjust div height to expand according to dynamically generated text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm receiving a description for a product through an API call of a service. This description, can be potentially to big to not fit on my div. This is my initial div:

```
<div class="div-info">
  <h1 class="equipment-name">Title</h1>
  <h4 class="equipment-city-state">{{equipment.coordinates.city}} - {{equipment.coordinates.state}}</h4>
  <ul class="equipment-price">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="equipment-city-state">{{equipment.coordinates.city}} - {{equipment.coordinates.state}}</p>
  <p class="service-description" [@visibilityChanged]="visibility[i]">{{equipment.description}}</p>
</div>
```

And this is what looks like:

[image]

And when the user clicks on the 'Ler mais' button should display the text, and if not fit in div, should increase the div. This is what looks like when the user clicks on the button

[image]

I would like the two first paragraphs [Lorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) would be entire displayed inside the `div`, even with the div height must be increased.

Comment: This is more of a CSS question than an Angular question, so it might be more important to show that than your HTML (it helps, though). That said, the simple answer to your question might be "Don't set a height property on the div."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your css so that the `divInfo` div will expand automatically to accommodate it's child elements:

```
.divInfo {
    height: auto;
}
```

---

**jsFiddle with dummy text:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/38rxe82m/

Try copy-pasting random long sentences or lists in the fiddle above and the `divInfo` will expand accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I needed use this property on other tag, but it worked!